# error installing Entity Framework Core SqlServer on VS 2017

Tags: sql-server, uwp, entity-framework-core

Does anyone have any ideas about how to fix this?

I have tried it various different ways and version on VS 2015, and then I just recently upgraded to VS 2017, but still have same issue.

I'm in the process of installing Entity Framework Core, and wanted to connect to a SqlServer.

When I install the package via Pack Man Console or via NuGet interface, I get the following error....

I have the following installed currently.. [image: I have the following installed currently..]

System.Threading.Thread 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Thread on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-arm.
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).
System.Threading.Thread 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Thread on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-arm-aot.
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm-aot).
System.Threading.Thread 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Thread on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x64.
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).
System.Threading.Thread 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Thread on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x64-aot.
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).
System.Threading.Thread 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Thread on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x86.
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).
System.Threading.Thread 4.3.0 provides a compile-time reference assembly for System.Threading.Thread on UAP,Version=v10.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win10-x86-aot.
One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86-aot).
**Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'RapidDeploy'.**

Thanks in advance for any help on this.
Randy

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the SQL Server provider with UWP applications, you must use the SQLite provider instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/

Comment: Do you have a link that backs that up? So, if what your saying is true, would I need to use EF6 and SqlServer instead? Surely there is a way to use some form of multi user database with a UWP app.

Comment: I have added a link - you can only access multi user database in UWP via a web service